# Backing up a directory on Ubuntu server.

Tags: server, backup

I have a minecraft server that runs on ubuntu server (headless). Hat I want to do is set up automatic backups to backup the "world" directory every night to my nas box.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: If the below answer helped you, please don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the small number at the left of the text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When I was running minecraft servers I used rsync to copy from my ramdisk into a physical backup.  Before you do this make sure you pause your world.  I also used this method to sync my ftp server and my game servers.

you can add a script into your crontab that pauses the world saves, then rsyncs to your backup directory, then re-enables world saves.  you can use rsync like this:

```
rsync -rh --progress path/to/minecraft/world user@nas.ip.address:/path/to/backup
```

If you need to provide login information, I recommend SSH keys as I have implemented [here](https://github.com/andrewmeyer/usefulscripts/blob/master/killingfloor.sh#L143)

Comment: The definition for sync_cmd is this:  SYNC_CMD="ssh -i $REMOTE_KEY -l $REMOTE_NAME"